# Illustrator background color

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I must have pressed some keyboard combination and now the document background between artboards is no more dark gray (as usual) but fully transparent. How to restore this?

I'm using Illustrator CS6 on OSX Mountain Lion.

Thanks

Comment: Transparency grid `Cmd + Shift + D` perhaps?

Comment: Transparency grid, that is :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the Show/Hide Artboards options under the View menu.
I'm not sure if this is the default key sequence or one I entered: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Could be `Window > Application Frame`

Or

`View > Overprint Preview`

Could also be.....

`View > Hide Transparency Grid`

Or

`View > Show Artbaords`